# What happened to Html.Mailto from MVC preview to final?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mailto

In some of the previews, there was an HTML-helper method for building mailto-links.

http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/05/aspnet-mvc-preview-using-the-mvc-ui-helpers/

I am not able to find that in the final release. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know they removed some of those `HTMLHelper`s from the final version. That might be one of them. Previews are generally notorious for changes. You might want to look at the MvcFutures project.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471

Answer (score 0):

Check the MvcFutures assembly.  I don't remember seeing it in either of the Release Candidates, but I believe it's in Futures.   Source for 1.0 (and futures) available at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few features that were in ASP.NET MVC were moved into MVC Futures for one reason or another.  Most was due to incompleteness before the RTM.  However I don't know why Html.Mailto would have been left out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@Html.DisplayFor` such as `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.emailAddress)` and it will produce an email link.